# custom directive is not validating form. why not?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

**What code changes need to be made to get the custom `countparens` directive below to provide the extra custom string validation shown below during form validation?**  The code below DOES successfully alert the user when the input field is empty, but it IS NOT alerting the user when the number of open parens `(` and close parens `)` is not equal.

I am using AngularJS.  I used [the documentation at this link (scroll to bottom)](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) to design the code below.

Here is the html for the form:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            <form name="userForm" ng-submit="rectangularForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                <input type="text" name="fieldname" ng-model="nameofjsontype.fieldname" required />
                <p ng-show="userForm.fieldname.$invalid && !userForm.fieldname.$pristine" class="help-block">Function is a required field.</p>
                <span ng-show="userForm.nameofjsontype.fieldname.$error.countparens">The #( != #) !</span>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" >Click to submit</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The javascript file containing the directive includes:

```
// create angular app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// create angular controller
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.nameofjsontype = {type:"nameofjsontype", fieldname: 'some (value) here.'};

    $scope.rectangularForm = function(isValid) {
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
          var funcJSON = {type:"nameofjsontype", fieldname: $scope.nameofjsontype.fieldname};
          $http.post('/server/side/controller', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
            $scope.nameofjsontype = response.data;
          });
        }
    };
}]);

myApp.directive('countparens', function() {
 return {
   require: 'ngModel',
   link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
     ctrl.$validators.countparens = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
       if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
         // consider empty models to be valid
         return true;
       }

       if (
        ($scope.nameofjsontype.fieldname.match(/\)/g).length) == ($scope.nameofjsontype.fieldname.match(/\(/g).length)
        ) {
         // it is valid
         return true;
       }

       // it is invalid
       return false;
     };
   }
 };
});
```

Comment: Can you provide a plunker with your code?

Comment: @lebobbi I am researching that, but I have never used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup should be using `userForm.fieldname.$error.countparens` to show the error. The field bound to the `userForm` is NOT the same as your `ngModel` value. See [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cn4x5N5p5wmPCvKhFZgU?p=preview) for what I mean

```
<span ng-show="userForm.fieldname.$error.countparens" class="help-block">The #( != #) !</span>
```

You are also not using your directive on your input element:

```
<input type="text" name="fieldname" ng-model="nameofjsontype.fieldname" required data-countparens=""/>
```

In your directive

- you should be using `modelValue` and not the scope value when doing your matching AND
- you need to cater for when there are no matches to `(` or `)`

.

```
myApp.directive('countparens', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$validators.countparens = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) ||
              ((modelValue.match(/\)/g) || []).length == (modelValue.match(/\(/g) || []).length);
          };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Actually, as I test your code, you made it so that alert for empty field also fires whenever there is an unequal number of parentheses.  So there are two messages when the number of open and close parens is unequal (which is wrong) and only one message when the field is empty (which is correct).  How can I adjust the code above so that it eliminates this remaining problem?

Comment: @CodeMed In that case you should be checking the `required` validation field `userForm.fieldname.$error.required` instead of just checking if it is invalid with `userForm.fieldname.$invalid` in your `ng-show`. See updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Cn4x5N5p5wmPCvKhFZgU?p=preview)

Comment: That did it.  Thank you for sharing your jedi knowledge.

Comment: I created a separate question about how to re-use the same directive in multiple forms.  Are you willing to help me with that also?  Here is the link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33404502/how-does-one-re-use-the-same-validation-for-multiple-forms-on-a-single-page-web