# how does one re-use the same directive for multiple forms web app?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, validation

**What changes need to be made to get the code below to successfully call the same validation directive from multiple different forms using AngularJS?**  Note that the first form is able to validate correctly, in that it checks for an even number of open parens `(` and close parens `)` and alerts the user immediately if the number is not equal.

However, when I try to get the second form to share the first directive, the second form fails to have the parens validation.  And when I create a duplicate directive with a different name and call the duplicate directive from the second form, the second form's validation disables submit when there are unequal numbers of open and close parens BUT FAILS TO NOTIFY THE USER.

It seems silly to have redundant directives when the same validation will be used on many forms in a site.

This might (or might not) be complicated by the fact that each form is in a different include that is exchanged in the same index.html in a single-page web application.  To rule out this possibility, I am including all the code required to reproduce the problem as follows:

`index.html` is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>iPlotmy</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="resources/css/my.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">

     <!-- build:js({app,.tmp}) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="js/lib/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-ui-router-statehelper.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-cookies.js"></script>
    <script src="js/lib/angular-storage.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myController.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="myController">  
<table width=100%>
<tr>
    <td colspan=3 align=center>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <button ng-click="firstLink()">first link</button>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <button ng-click="secondLink()">second link</button>
                </th>

        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
          <div ng-if="linktype == 'first'">
            <div ng-include="'index_firstinclude.html'"></div>
          </div>
          <div ng-if="linktype == 'second'">
            <div ng-include="'index_secondinclude.html'"></div>
          </div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The `index_firstinclude.html` is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            <form name="userForm" ng-submit="firstForm(userForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                <input type="text" name="func1" ng-model="firstplot.func1" required data-countparens=""/>
            <p ng-show="userForm.func1.$error.required && !userForm.func1.$pristine" class="help-block">Function is a required field.</p>
            <p ng-show="userForm.func1.$error.countparens" class="help-block">The number of open parentheses ( does not equal the number of close parentheses ) !</p>
                <br>
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="userForm.$invalid" >Click to Submit</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The `index_secondinclude.html` is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width=200>
            <form name="mysecondForm" ng-submit="secondForm(mysecondForm.$valid)" novalidate>
                <input type="text" name="func1" ng-model="secondplot.func1" required data-countparens=""/>
                <p ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.required && !mysecondForm.func1.$pristine" class="help-block">Function is a required field.</p>
                <p ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.countparenssecond" class="help-block">The number of open parentheses ( does not equal the number of close parentheses ) !</p>
                <br>
                theta min: <input type="text" ng-model="secondplot.tmin"/>
                <br>
                theta max: <input type="text" ng-model="secondplot.tmax"/>
                <button type="submit" ng-disabled="mysecondForm.$invalid" >Click to Submit</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

The relevant parts of the `myController.js` file:

```
// create angular app
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

// create angular controller
myApp.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.linktype = 'home';
$scope.firstplot = {type:"firstplot", func1: 'some (test) value'};
$scope.secondplot = {type:"secondplot", func1: 'another (test) value'};

    $scope.firstForm = function(isValid) {
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
          var funcJSON = {type:"firstplot", func1: $scope.firstplot.func1};
          $http.post('/path/to/first-server-url', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
            $scope.firstplot = response.data;
          });
        }
    };

    $scope.secondForm = function(isValid) {
        console.log("inside secondForm")
        if (isValid) {
        $scope.secondplot.uri = "resources/images/plot-second-equation.gif";
        var funcJSON = {type:"secondplot", func1: $scope.secondplot.func1};
        $http.post('/path/to/second-server-url', funcJSON).then(function(response) {
            $scope.secondplot = response.data;
        });
        }
    };

    //below functions handle navigation links
    $scope.firstLink = function() {
        $scope.linktype = 'first';
    }
    $scope.secondLink = function() {
        $scope.linktype = 'second';
    }

}]);

/// below directive(s) for form validation
myApp.directive('countparens', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$validators.countparens = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) ||
              ((modelValue.match(/\)/g) || []).length == (modelValue.match(/\(/g) || []).length);
          };
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive('countparenssecond', function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$validators.countparenssecond = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
            return ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue) ||
          ((modelValue.match(/\)/g) || []).length == (modelValue.match(/\(/g) || []).length);
          };
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Just a typo I suspect, you don't need the second directive. Just change your second form from `ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.countparenssecond"` to `ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.countparens"`

Comment: @user2341963 Thank you.  I made your change and also commented out the `countparenssecond` directive in the controller.  But now the second form still does not print out the warning about unequal parens.  It blanks out the submit button when there is an unequal number of parens.  It also shows the required field warning when the field is empty.  But it does not show the unequal parens method when the number of parens is not equal.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, working for me [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/SUyAaFZJ9ffm8SRrM6vy?p=preview)

Comment: @user2341963 Then why doesn't it work at this link? http://plnkr.co/edit/rxT7qItJpfHkpaLaz850

Comment: In your second form, you should not be using `ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.countparenssecond"` but rather `ng-show="mysecondForm.func1.$error.countparens"`. See your [forked plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/azHP37pPNEOK2nY24BuJ?p=preview)

Comment: @user2341963 I think that there was an unrelated problem elsewhere in my setup.  This is resolved now.  The problem was not changing the name to just `countparens`, though that did reduce redundancy in the code.  Thank you for looking into this.  You helped me dig deeper to find the seemingly unrelated underlying cause.

Comment: Cool, glad you sorted it out on your own